# Creating a Pie Chart with 2 columns

Tags: 2010, list, chart-web-part

I have a list that has two columns (closed tickets & total tickets) I would like to create a pie chart depicting closed tickets vs open tickets. I thought this would be a standard function but I'm finding out its not.

```
Title | Closed | Total 
  A       3       3  
  B       4       5 
  C       0       2
```

So what I want to show is a Pie chart with 2 sections (7 Closed Tickets vs 3 Open Tickets). I am able to calculate remaining tickets with a new column but that's not the issue. The Pie charts give me a separate pie chart for each column with or with out the calculated column (ex. Closed Pie chart with sections A,B,C And Total Pie chart with Sections A,B,C)